# Always getting error 'The following packages have unmet dependencies' when I want to install new packages

Tags: apt, server, package-management, proxy

When I get some new packages using

```
`sudo apt update
sudo apt install <packages>`
```

I always got error message like

```
`The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 squid : Depends: libecap3 (>= 1.0.1) but it is not going to be installed
         Depends: squid-common (>= 5.7-0ubuntu0.22.04.3) but it is not going to be installed
         Depends: libdbi-perl but it is not going to be installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt --fix-broken install' with no packages (or specify a solution).`
```

So I always do sudo apt --fix-broken install but it also show

```
`Use 'sudo apt autoremove' to remove them.
Suggested packages:
  openjdk-11-demo openjdk-11-source
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  openjdk-11-jdk-headless
0 upgraded, 1 newly installed, 0 to remove and 165 not upgraded.
1 not fully installed or removed.
Need to get 73.5 MB of archives.
After this operation, 81.9 MB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
Get:1 http://mirror.kakao.com/ubuntu jammy-updates/main amd64 openjdk-11-jdk-headless amd64 11.0.21+9-0ubuntu1~22.04 [73.5 MB]
Err:1 http://mirror.kakao.com/ubuntu jammy-updates/main amd64 openjdk-11-jdk-headless amd64 11.0.21+9-0ubuntu1~22.04
  Error reading from server - read (104: Connection reset by peer) [IP: 113.29.189.165 80]
E: Failed to fetch http://mirror.kakao.com/ubuntu/pool/main/o/openjdk-lts/openjdk-11-jdk-headless_11.0.21%2b9-0ubuntu1%7e22.04_amd64.deb  Error reading from server - read (104: Connection reset by peer) [IP: 113.29.189.165 80]
E: Unable to fetch some archives, maybe run apt-get update or try with --fix-missing?`
```

I thought if I use proxy server, then I can download it.
So I tried make proxy server in ubuntu by using package squid but I met the first error message again

Every packages I want to install show the error messages
please save me from the errors I'm going crazy...
thanks for every advice

When I'm facing the errors first with installing libglpk-dev for downloading ChIPseeker package in R, I tried to make proxy server but it's failed with same errors

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I resolve unmet dependencies after adding a PPA?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/140246/how-do-i-resolve-unmet-dependencies-after-adding-a-ppa)

Comment: Thanks I'll try that.
And I'm so sorry to ask this, I don't know how open the Ubuntu software in software sources window. 
I read some questions and I often faced that windows and I think it is MacOS, but I installed ubuntu in Windows with wsl. So I want to check the setting of Ubuntu but I cannot find it. I'm new to ubuntu, so I don't know well...